# What's the miniumum Java SDK for using Mutiny?

Tags: mutiny

I want to ask what's the minimum Java SDK for implementing Mutiny? Is it possible to implement this using Java 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, Mutiny requires Java 8.
There are discussions to switch to Java 11.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. I very much appreciate it.